# Can i sample sets of data within a dataframe without selecting the same set twice (without replacement)?

Tags: python, pandas, random, sample, sample-data

I am fairly new to python and i would like to sample sets of data in the following dataframe by their group, without selecting the same group twice. The code i have written does sample the sets of data correctly, however, it can select the same set twice.

please note: the following data is testing data and the actual data i am using the code on is much larger in size and therefore using indexes will not be possible.

**DATA:**

````
d={'group': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','E','E','E'], 'number': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'weather':['hot','hot','hot','cold','cold','cold','hot','hot','hot','cold','cold','cold','hot','hot','hot']}```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
group   number  weather
A       1       hot
A       2       hot
A       3       hot
B       1       cold
B       2       cold
B       3       cold
C       1       hot
C       2       hot
C       3       hot
D       1       cold
D       2       cold
D       3       cold
E       1       hot
E       2       hot
E       3       hot
````

**MY CODE**

```
df_s=[]
for typ in df.group.sample(3,replace=False):
    df_s.append(df[df['group']==typ])
df_s=pd.concat(df_s)
df_s
```

**OUTCOME**

```
group   number  weather
E       1       hot
E       2       hot
E       3       hot
E       1       hot
E       2       hot
E       3       hot
D       1       cold
D       2       cold
D       3       cold
```

The outcome should give 3 different groups data however as can be seen there is only 2 (E & D) meaning the code can select the same group more than once.

Comment: You can use `np.random.seed(32)` to make the data reproducible. You can replace the value `32` with any value you would like. So if you share your code or if you re-run the code, you will generate the same random sample of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `sample` used with argument `replace=False` will ensure, that you have no **row duplicates** in created sample df. However you do have several rows with the same letter denoting group (your column `group`).

For just quickfixing your code:

```
df_s=[]
for typ in np.random.choice(df["group"].unique(), 3, replace=False):
    df_s.append(df[df['group']==typ])
df_s=pd.concat(df_s)
df_s
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated!